# Unable to retrieve NULL data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three fields Category, Date, and ID. I need to retrieve data that does not belong under certain ID. Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN('1','2','3')
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

After running this query I should only get records that do not have any ID meaning NULL values because for yesterday's record only ID 1,2,3 exist and rest do not have any value (NULL). For some reason when I run the query it takes away the NULL values as well so I end up with 0 rows. This is very stranger to me and I do not understand what is the cause. All I know that the ID numbers are string values. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why dont you add `AND ID IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Is `ID` the primary key?

Comment: ID is not the primary key. I would want ID 4 in future if it exist so my intention is not to only get NULL values but that is what I am left with right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. NULL values cannot not be equated to anything else.

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE (ID NOT IN('1','2','3') OR ID IS NULL)
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already shown how to fix this, so let me try to explain *why* this happens.

```
WHERE ID NOT IN('1','2','3')
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE ID <> '1' AND ID <> '2' AND ID <> '3'
```

Since `NULL <> anything` yields UNKNOWN, your expression yields UNKNOWN and the record in question is not returned.

See the following Wikipedia article for details on this *ternary logic*:

- [Null (SQL): Comparisons with NULL and the three-valued logic (3VL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)

Comment: So let's say today I get records for ID = 4, will it be part of the result with NULL values. I just want to clarify that I do not just want to get NULL values, I want to get everything but ID 1,2,3 but since yesterday's data doesn't have any other IDs, I am left with NULL records.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NULL comparison search conditions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270(v=sql.105).aspx).

> Use the IS NULL or IS NOT NULL clauses to test for a NULL value. This
>   can add complexity to the WHERE clause. For example, the TerritoryID
>   column in the AdventureWorks2008R2 Customer table allows null values.
>   If a SELECT statement is to test for null values in addition to
>   others, it must include an IS NULL clause:
>
> ```
> SELECT CustomerID, AccountNumber, TerritoryID
> FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.Customer
> WHERE TerritoryID IN (1, 2, 3)
>    OR TerritoryID IS NULL
> ```

If you really want to be able to compare values to NULL's directly, you can do that as well. This is also described in the above article:

> Transact-SQL supports an extension that allows for the comparison
>   operators to return TRUE or FALSE when comparing against null values.
>   This option is activated by setting ANSI_NULLS OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about you want ID fields as null?

Here is how you do it: (Assumins rest of your query is ok)

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ID IS NULL
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

If you want records that does not have a category than you need to change your query as

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE Category IS NULL
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a couple of options:

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ISNULL(ID, '4') NOT IN('1','2','3')
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

Or what su8898 said

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ID N
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you use "IN" or "NOT IN" which will not fetch any values if the column has got NULL values..

In your case, if you want to fetch only records with ID=NULL, then you can try the solution **vgSefa** suggested above..

If you want to pull all records with NULL as well as ID NOT IN('1','2','3'), then you could try something like this..

```
SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ID IS NULL
AND Date = '01/06/2015'

UNION ALL

SELECT Category, Date, ID
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN('1','2','3')
AND ID IS NOT NULL
AND Date = '01/06/2015'
```

Comment: GREAT Thank you! Second option is what I want: NULL values plus 4,5,6.. IDs